# Why not cast to MutableList since I set .toMutableList()

Tags: android, kotlin

I have cast this code to mutable list. But for some reason it still indicate it as a list.
This is my code

```
        return (stringToArray(userSharedPrefs.getString(MY_KEY, null))?.toMutableList()?.distinct()?.reversed() ?: mutableListOf<String>())
```

But got this error

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
MutableList<String>
Found:
List<String>
```

Why it says `Found: List<String>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`distinct()` and `reversed()` return new Lists, not MutableLists. You need to put `toMutableList()` *after* those calls.

```
return (stringToArray(userSharedPrefs.getString(MY_KEY, null))?.distinct()?.reversed()?.toMutableList() ?: mutableListOf<String>())
```

However, it would be more robust to follow the idiomatic pattern of returning a read-only List from your function anyway, if you are able to change the return type to List. This function does not need the list to be mutable after it's done with it. The consumer can decide whether it needs a MutableList and use `toMutableList()` if it needs to.

Also, to clarify terminology. `toMutableList()` does not *cast* to a MutableList. It copies the contents into a new MutableList. Casting has a very specific meaning. It means getting the compiler to treat an object instance as a different type without changing the instance that's being referenced. Copying to a MutableList is safe, but casting (using `as MutableList`) is unsafe and can crash at runtime. Even safe-casting to MutableList  with `as? MutableList` is actually unsafe because some of the MutableLists used under the hood in the Kotlin standard library throw runtime exceptions when you try to mutate them.